# Generate a unique IV header

Tags: linux, bash, cgi, uniqueidentifier, initialization-vector

I need to generate a unique `IV (Initialization Vector)` header.

The IV **SHALL** be 96 bits long, comprised of the year (16 bits, 0 to
65535), the current time (64 bits, nanoseconds this year), and a counter (16 bits) to generate a 96-bit IV.

How can I generate this unique identifier in `CGI bash script`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in y2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
d2b() {
    printf "%0${2}s\n" $(bc <<< "obase=2;$1")|tr ' ' '0'
}

counter=1
eval "$(date +'firstday=%Y-01-01 now=%s nano=%N year=%Y')"
midnight=$(date -d "$firstday 0" +%s)
seconds=$((now - midnight))
header=$(d2b $year 16)$(d2b $seconds$nano 64)$(d2b $counter 16)
echo header: $header
```

- function() { ... } - define a custom function in bash
- bc <<< "obase=2;$1 - decimal to binary the 1st parameter with sed
- printf "%0${2}s\n" | ... | tr - fill with leading zeroes to length $2
- eval date... - put the current time into variables
- date -d "$firstday 0" +%s  - unixtime at jan1 00:00 (seconds)

run it:

```
$ ./y2.sh
header: 000001111110000000000000011000100101000110110001011001011100011000011100010000010000000000000001
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, works fine for me. Could you please explain it in detail?